# How to solve LLDB error about N_SO in symbol with UID 1

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, reverse-engineering, lldb

When I launched lldb to debug an iOS application, I got an error that I never had before.

> error: Veriff(0x00000001018cc000) N_SO in symbol with UID 1 has
>   invalid sibling in debug map, please file a bug and attach the binary
>   listed in this error

Below is the context of the error.

```
(lldb) process connect connect://localhost:6666
error: Veriff(0x00000001018cc000) N_SO in symbol with UID 1 has invalid sibling in debug map, please file a bug and attach the binary listed in this error
Process 3270 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x0000000187a1f6b0 libxpc.dylib` _xpc_dictionary_apply_node_f  + 108
libxpc.dylib`_xpc_dictionary_apply_node_f:
->  0x187a1f6b0 <+108>: mov    x1, x20
    0x187a1f6b4 <+112>: blr    x21
    0x187a1f6b8 <+116>: tbz    w0, #0x0, 0x187a1f6f8     ; <+180>
    0x187a1f6bc <+120>: mov    x0, x26
    0x187a1f6c0 <+124>: cbnz   x26, 0x187a1f6a0          ; <+92>
    0x187a1f6c4 <+128>: add    x22, x22, #0x1            ; =0x1 
    0x187a1f6c8 <+132>: cmp    x22, x23
    0x187a1f6cc <+136>: b.lo   0x187a1f698               ; <+84>
Target 0: (Test app) stopped.
```

Has anyone been able to solve this error?

Does this impact any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen that error triggered before.  If you can make this binary available to us, please file a bug either with http://bugs.llvm.org or http://bugreporter.apple.com and include the error message and the binary.

The error means lldb can't map symbols from some .o file that was included in your binary back to the .o file they came from (which is where the debug information actually resides.)  So that code's debug information will not be available.